# Filtering out keys of a map but keeping all values in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter, sum

I'm trying to write a method with the following signature:

```scala
def buildSumMap(minInterval:Int, mappes:SortedMap[Int, Long]):SortedMap[Int, Long] = {...}
```

Within the method I want to return a new map by applying the following pseudo-code to each
`(key:Int,value:Long)`-pair of "mappes":

```scala
If(key + minInterval > nextKey) {
    value += nextValue
}
else {
    //Forget previous key(s) and return current key with sum of all previous values
    return (key, value)
}
```

Example: If I had the source Map `((10 -> 5000), (20 -> 5000), (25 -> 7000), (40 -> 13000))` and defined a minInterval of 10, I'd expect the resulting Map:

`((10 -> 5000), (25 -> 12000), (40 -> 13000))`

I found a lot of examples for transforming keys **and** values of filtering keys and values seperately but none so far for *dropping* keys, while preserving the values.

Comment: What if your last key was 30 instead of 40?

Comment: Then the resulting map should be `((10 -> 5000), (30 -> 25000))` since I first check if (current key + intervall) is within range of the next key, before I return the KeyValue-pair.

To be honest though: My main problem is wrapping my head around filtering/reducing and summing Maps at the same time in a "scala-ish" way. The filtering logic itself isn't that high on my priority list.

Comment: As far as I understand the condition should be `key + minInterval > nextKey` (or `nextKey - key < minInterval`) - keys with small interval merges into one, with larger key, right?

Comment: You are right of course. I really do care more about how to realize the filtering than the filter itself. I adjusted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, basically there is no totally simple way of doing this, because the requirement isn't simple. You need to somehow iterate through the SortedMap while comparing adjacent elements and build a new Map. There are several ways to do it:

1. Use a fold / reduce / scan / groupBy higher order functions: generally the preferred way, and most concise
2. Recursion (see http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/ for plenty of examples): what you resort to if using higher order functions gets too complicated, or the exact function you need doesn't exist. May be faster than using functions.
3. Builders - a nice term for a brief foray into mutable-land. Best performance; often equivalent to the recursive version without the ceremony

Here's my attempt using `scanLeft`:

```
def buildSumMap(minInterval: Int, mappes: SortedMap[Int, Long]) = 
  SortedMap.empty[Int, Long] ++ mappes.toSeq.tail.scanLeft(mappes.head){
    case ((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) => if (k2 - k1 > minInterval) (k2,v2) else (k1,v2)
  }.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
```

It looks complicated but it isn't really, once you understand what `scanLeft` and `groupBy` do, which you can look up elsewhere. It basically scans the sequence from the left and compares the keys, using the key to the left if the gap is too small, then groups the tuples together according to the keys.

TLDR: The key is to learn the built-in functions in the collections library, which takes some practice, but it's good fun.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses `List` as intermediate structure. It traverses map from left to right and appends key-value pairs to list if interval is big enough, otherwise it replaces head of the list with new key-value pair. `TreeMap` factory metod reverses list at the end.

```
import collection.immutable._

def buildSumMap(minInterval:Int, mappes:SortedMap[Int, Long]):SortedMap[Int, Long] = 
  TreeMap(
    mappes.foldLeft[List[(Int, Long)]] (Nil) { 
      case (Nil, nextKV) => nextKV :: Nil
      case (acc @ (key, value) :: accTail, nextKV @ (nextKey, nextValue)) =>
        if (nextKey - key < minInterval)
          (nextKey -> (value + nextValue)) :: accTail
        else
          nextKV :: acc
    } : _*
  )
```

Comment: My function joins near pairs if interval between keys is lesser than `minInterval`. For new pair larger key is taken, values are added. Author said that filtering logic is not important, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.collection.SortedMap

def buildSumMap(minInterval:Int, mappes:SortedMap[Int, Long]):SortedMap[Int, Long] = {
  def _buildSumMap(map: List[(Int, Long)], buffer: List[(Int, Long)], result:SortedMap[Int, Long]): SortedMap[Int, Long] = {
    def mergeBufferWithResult = {
        val res = buffer.headOption.map { case (k, v) =>
            (k, buffer.map(_._2).sum)
          }
        res.map(result + _).getOrElse(result)
    }

    map match {
        case entry :: other =>
          if(buffer.headOption.exists(entry._1 - _._1 < minInterval)) {
            _buildSumMap(other, entry :: buffer, result)
          } else {
            _buildSumMap(other, entry :: Nil, mergeBufferWithResult)
          }
        case Nil =>
          mergeBufferWithResult
    }
  }
  _buildSumMap(mappes.toList, List.empty, SortedMap.empty)
}

val result = buildSumMap(10 , SortedMap(10 -> 5000L, 20 -> 5000L, 25 -> 7000L,  40 -> 13000L))

println(result)
```

//Map(10 -> 5000, 25 -> 12000, 40 -> 13000)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to split the parts of the algorithm :

```
import scala.collection._

val myMap = SortedMap((10 -> 5000), (20 -> 5000), (25 -> 7000), (40 -> 13000)).mapValues(_.toLong)


def filterInterval(minInterval: Int, it: Iterable[Int]):List[Int] = {
    val list = it.toList
    val jumpMap = list.map(x => (x, list.filter( _ > x + minInterval))).toMap.
        filter(_._2.nonEmpty).mapValues(_.min)

    def jump(n:Int): Stream[Int] = jumpMap.get(n).map(j => Stream.cons(j, jump(j))).getOrElse(Stream.empty)

    list.min :: jump(list.min).toList
}


def buildSumMap(minInterval:Int, mappes:Map[Int, Long]):Map[Int,Long] = {
    val filteredKeys: List[Int] =  filterInterval(minInterval, mappes.keys)

    val agg:List[(Int, Long)] = filteredKeys.map(finalkey => 
        (finalkey,mappes.filterKeys(_ <= finalkey).values.sum)
    ).sort(_._1 < _._1)

    agg.zip((filteredKeys.min, 0L) :: agg ).map(st => (st._1._1, st._1._2 - st._2._2)).toMap
}

     buildSumMap(10, myMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take:

```
def buildSumMap(map: SortedMap[Int, Int], diff: Int) = 
  map.drop(1).foldLeft(map.take(1)) { case (m, (k, v)) =>
    val (_k, _v) = m.last
    if (k - _k < diff) (m - _k) + (k -> (v + _v))
    else m + (k -> v)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner (than my first attempt) solution using Scalaz 7's `State`, and a `List` to store the state of the computation. Using a `List` makes it efficient to inspect, and modify if necessary, the `head` of the list at each step.

```
def f2(minInterval: Int): ((Int, Int)) => State[List[(Int, Int)], Unit] = {
  case (k, v) => State {
    case (floor, acc) :: tail if (floor + minInterval) > k =>
      ((k, acc + v) :: tail) -> ()
    case state => ((k, v) :: state) -> ()
  }
}

scala> mappes.toList traverseS f2(10) execZero
res1: scalaz.Id.Id[List[(Int, Int)]] = List((40,13000), (25,12000), (10,5000))
```